# Optional Chaining doesn't result in undefined in Typescript

Tags: typescript

If I have an array of arrays, then it isn't safe to blindly do

`const a = array[index1][index2]` since `array[index1]` could be `undefined`, leading to an error. What I expected to occur when I defended with `const a = array[index1]?.[index2]` was to have `a` be a union type with `undefined`. That's not what I get, though- I see it as the type of the underlying array.

How do I defend in code such that TS can pick up the potential for `undefined` at compile time?

MCVE:

```
type A = {
    owner?: string,
    feline?: string
}

const arr: Array<Array<A>> = []

const item = arr[2]?.[5]; // typed as A rather than A|undefined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your tsConfig option, add this line

```json
{
"compilerOptions":{
   //... something else
   "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true
 }
}
```

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1/#checked-indexed-accesses-nouncheckedindexedaccess

https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess

[image]

[image]

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=false#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeAoK6oHsDuA7CATgPwBcUAzsAQJa4DmANGhgGYQA2tEpFVtdKAL4oUAY0y5KUAIYECZGHOkgAPIoLK1APi0IoAbQC6I8ZOBRqwCAFs9sgvoBMhogDp9AVkMBuKCgD0-hhQAHpEIkA)